# How to create a Bootstrap Sass project

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I know that could be multiple answers for this question but I would know how i can fast setting up project with Bootstrap and Sass.

I had never used node, npm, grunt or bower, I've installed all already but i can't really find a good tutorial for:

- Setting up the project structure
- Auto compile sass files on save
- (Maybe) Live reload in chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not using any boilerplate for your first project as you want to get into the "guts" of it, and once you are familiar with basics, then you can try boilerplate and see what they can do for you.

Few tools you would need to setup a project from scratch includes: [Node's npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node), [Bower](https://bower.io/#install-bower), [Gulp (for example)](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

After you have those installed, you can dig in into creating your first project.

1) [Initialize your npm project](http://weaintplastic.github.io/web-development-field-guide/Development/Frontend_Development/Setting_up_your_project/Setup_Dependency_Managers/Node_Package_Manager/Initialize_NPM_on_a_new_project.html)

2) [Pull the packages with Bower (Bootstrap scss for starters)](https://bower.io/#getting-started)

2a) [Pull the Specific Bootstrap 3 SCSS port](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#c-bower)

3) [Configure Basic Gulp-scss config for your SCSS needs.](http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-gulp-and-sass/)

Basic idea behind Bower is that you have unmodified source of plugins/3rd party js/css in bower_components folder, and you use those files to compile a production ready files (js/css). What this means is that your bower_components folder is a "src" folder, and you have to add your "dist" or distributable files. Gulp helps with this part.

For the project structure, [further readings](http://blog.rangle.io/angular-gulp-bestpractices/) and improvements on gulp tasks.

Once you have basic working project, you can try expanding your gulp-config with, like you mentioned [Browser Sync](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp) and others.

I did compile a "general tasks" gulp file that i use from project to project. You can take a [look here](https://github.com/synchromatik/GulpFileGeneralConfig) and use it if you find it fits.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Aldryn's boilerplate:

https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-boilerplate-bootstrap3

[Documentation](http://aldryn-boilerplate-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general/index.html)

Comment: Thank for you answer but as i had already described in the question i'm very new to bower npm etc. For example documentation say: 
**npm install to install the requirements from package.json**
**bower install to install the requirements from bower.json via .bowerrc**
but where are package.json and bower.json?

Comment: @koMah First you need to download the repository from: https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-boilerplate-bootstrap3.
Then you just need to follow the steps listed in the documentation: http://aldryn-boilerplate-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general/installation.html

   Hope it helps.